# jQuery.val not working on range input?

Tags: jquery, input, range

`<input type="range" value="5,17" />`

If I try to change the value with `$('input').val('8,20');` it doesn't change...

But on hidden inputs works:
`<input type="hidden" value="s" />`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The HTML5 `<input type="range" />` does only handle one value between `min` and `max` attribute - e.g.:

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="5.3" step="0.1" />

$("input[type=range]").val(); // returns 5.3
$("input[type=range]").val(6); // sets value to 6
$("input[type=range]").val(); // returns 6
```

If you want to have the slide handle a min **and** a max value in one UI-input you could possibly use jQueryUI's slider: https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

Comment: I'd also recommend jQueryUI's slider for better browser compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

I tried setting up a fiddle and it worked without problems.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z2B7Y/

Keep in mind that the `value` represents the *numerical value*, that's between the `min` and `max` attributes. Trying to set it to `8,20` it's not valid, because it's not a valid number and therefore doesn't make sense.

If you want to set a floating point value you have to use the dot, e.g.

```
$('input').val('8.20');
```

If you want to set instead the bounds of the range you have to change the properties, e.g.

```
$('input').prop('min','8');
$('input').prop('max','20');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, actually i'm using this plugin: https://github.com/tommoor/tinyrange-jquery-plugin. But I wanted to set the value of the slider to the input...

Comment: Can you make an example of what you're trying to do? Because as you can see in the fiddle you can definitely change the `value` of the `input`; just be sure to correctly pass the floating point value.