# cakephp getting values from fields with datatype datetime and decimal(10,0) in jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, cakephp, datetime

I'm a beginner in cakephp 2.X platform. I created one MySQL-table with filed type *datetime* and *decimal(10,0)* and in the `view.ctp` add two statement

```
echo $this->Form->input('date_expiry',array('label'=>'Expiration Date'));
echo $this->Form->input('coupon_rank',array('label'=>'Coupon Rank'));
```

then automatically it show one datetime field and one selectbox with range value.
but I cant get its value using jQuery. i tried both using id.

```
var date_expiry=$('#CouponDateExpiry').val();
var coupon_rank=$('#CouponCouponrank').find('option:selected').val();
```

Is there any way to get its value using jQuery? I also want to validate that the date that is entered is less than the current date. How is this done?

Comment: your means in textbox it displays value but in jquery you are not getting value,right?

Comment: @Er.KT ya , it is not a text box, datetime field and one range value box.now i can select date-time and range valuesand it is saving to the database, but only the problem with validation. how to get the value using jquery

Comment: I see nothing here about the [tag:jquery-validate] plugin.  Removed tag.

Comment: Please can you update and mark answer

Answer (score 0):

For range tyep use

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="5.3" step="0.1" />

$("input[type=range]").val(); // returns 5.3
$("input[type=range]").val(6); // set value to 6
$("input[type=range]").val(); // returns 6
```

[jQuery.val not working on range input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921368/jquery-val-not-working-on-range-input)

For datepicker
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/get-the-value-from-a-datepicker-field

Comment: am not sure with datepicker